# Why ASP.NET site doesn't connect to SQL Server database,using SQL Server authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I created a database in SQL Server 2012 Express. The default login to the server through authenticated Windows, but during the installation set up the possibility of authentication SQL Server. Added the `.mdf` file to the ASP.NET MVC site, connect it via the connection string - all is well.

Connection string:

```
<add name="GnrlBase" 
     connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\articlesbase2.mdf;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I decided to change the authentication - SQL Server with login and password (so that other developers can work on the site locally, maybe I'm wrong and Windows authentication also be approached). Using Management Studio, I added a login for the server and user for the database, has appointed it the right db_owner, allowed ticks all the action at all to the server. Checked - in Management Studio with this username password connection is made, you can go to the table, everything works. I changed the connection string on the site.

```
<add name="GnrlBase" 
     connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\articlesbase2.mdf;User Id=mylogin;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When trying to connect to the database fails with the following error:

> Login failed for user '*the user who successfully connected to the management studio*'

Why???

Comment: Add your password in quotes, like Password='yourPassword'

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the first wrong answer.

I think [this website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) should help to understand how your connectionstring works.

@Zippy was right.

> Standard Security
>
> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;
>
> SQL Server 2000
>
> SQL Server 2005
>
> SQL Server 2008
>
> SQL Server 2012
>
> SQL Server 7.0
>
> Trusted Connection
>
> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
>
> SQL Server 2000
>
> SQL Server 2005
>
> SQL Server 2008
>
> SQL Server 2012
>
> SQL Server 7.0
>
> Connection to a SQL Server instance
>
> The server/instance name syntax used in the server option is the same
>   for all SQL Server connection strings.
>   Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User
>   Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;
>
> SQL Server 2000
>
> SQL Server 2005
>
> SQL Server 2008
>
> SQL Server 2012
>
> SQL Server 7.0

Comment: He's asking why he can't connect with user&password, your answer doesn't provide help for that. Edit and i'll remove the downvote.

Comment: If I did not answer directly to the question because I think the connectionstring is wrong. this answer may help I think.
The provider is not even the good one.
Look to the first connection string.

Comment: Please reread the question, he said that the 1st connection is working, the second one is wrong.

Comment: And? If i using mdf file, attached to project, what connectionstring i should use? Why Integrated Security work, but SQL auth not work? Sorry for my stupid questions(